# Memory being consumed while reading json files

Tags: python, json, dataframe, memory

I am trying to read several json files and append them on a dataframe.
By doing so my whole system memory is being consumed which is slowing down all the process.

I found that pd.read_json() will make copy of each json file and store it in the memory. I am trying to delete these dataframes from memory. Is there something wrong in implementation

```
def read_json(filename):
file = []
start = time.time()
for i in filename:
    x = pd.read_json(i, lines=True)
    file.append(x)
    del x
data = pd.concat(file, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
return(data)
```

How can I delete the dataframes.

If they are being deleted than what is causing my memory loss

Comment: Python memory allocation is automatic. By deleting an object you're not deleting the memory associated to it, it is the garbage collector that will eventually take care of it. Have a look at https://docs.python.org/3.7/c-api/memory.html

Comment: I want them to get garbage as I am constantly getting data

Answer (score 0):

You can force the garbage collector to release unreferenced memory:

```
import gc
gc.collect()
```